# Completing the square modulo $p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

(Admittedly, this question is inspired by one of the questions I was thinking for my Algebraic Number Theory class but I don't think the question that I am about to ask needs much knowledge of Algebraic Number Theory.)

Suppose $d$ is an integer that is congruent to $1$ mod $4$, so that $\frac{d-1}{4}$ is an integer. Let $p$ be an odd prime. I was thinking about when will this equation $X^2-X-\frac{d-1}{4}$ have repeated roots modulo $p$?

I know that we can rewrite this equation as $(X-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{d}{4}$ and so does it imply that $\frac{d}{4}\equiv0$ mod $p$? I cannot see why it would imply this and besides, couldn't we 'complete the square in a different way' because $X^2-X-\frac{d-1}{4}\equiv X^2-(1+mp)X-\frac{d-1}{4}$ for any integer $m$ and then we use the latter expression to complete the square and we could potentially get a different answer?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question, there are a few points to be made, so let me proceed in order.
Let $f(x) = x^2 - x - (d-1)/4 = (x-1/2)^2 - d/4$. I will always tacitly use the fact that $p$ is odd.

**Sometimes there are no roots**

Suppose there is a solution to $f(x)\equiv 0$ modulo $p$. Then $(2x-1)^2 \equiv d$. But this is not always possible to solve: it depends if $d$ is a quadratic residue or not, modulo $p$.

*If $d$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then $f(x)$ has no roots modulo $p$.*

**There are roots if and only if $\sqrt d$ exists modulo $p$**

Viceversa, suppose that $d$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. This means that there is some residue $s$ modulo $p$ such that $(-\pm s)^2 \equiv d$ modulo $p$. Moreover, each quadratic residue has at most two squareroots modulo $p$, namely $+s$ and $-s$ (*).

But then solving $f(x)\equiv 0$ is equivalent to solve the congruence $2x-1 \equiv \pm s$. We may use the notation $''s = \sqrt d''$ because indeed $s$ is a choice of squareroot residue modulo $d$. With this notation we get:

*If $d$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then the congruence $f(x)\equiv 0$ has the following solutions:*
$$ x \equiv \frac 1 2 \pm \frac {\sqrt d} 2 .$$

**There are roots if and only if $\sqrt \Delta$ exists modulo $p$**

This is part of a bigger truth, and all comes down to the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$. In this case the discriminant of $f(x)$ is precisely
$$\Delta = 1+(d-1) = d.$$

It comes with no surprise then that *the solutions of the quadratic congruence $f(x)\equiv 0$ are
$$x\equiv \frac{-b \pm \sqrt \Delta}{2a} = \frac {1\pm \sqrt d}{2},$$
provided that $\Delta$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

**Factorization approach**

One simple alternative way to approach the problem is by trying to factorize after completing the square. We have seen that, if $d$ is not a quadratic residue, then there are no solutions. If instead $d$ possesses a squareroot $s$ modulo $p$, which we will just denote $\sqrt d$, then the polynomial $f(x)$ can be seen as a difference of squares, and so it factors:

$$f(x) = \left (x-\frac 1 2 \right)^2  - \left(\frac {\sqrt d } 2\right)^2 = \left(x-\frac 1 2 +\frac {\sqrt d } 2\right)\left(x-\frac 1 2 -\frac {\sqrt d } 2\right).$$

Now, remember that products modulo $p$ have the property $$AB\equiv 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad A\equiv 0 \quad or \quad B\equiv 0.$$
This is true because $p$ is prime!

Then we can solve the linear factors separately, and get the "two" solutions.

**Repeated roots**

Now that we found the roots, we see that they are equal if and only if $+\sqrt d \equiv -\sqrt d$. This simply means $\sqrt d\equiv 0$. This means $d=0$.

Note that $d\equiv 0$ automatically implies that $\sqrt d$ exists modulo $p$ (and is equal to zero :)

This is again part of a bigger truth:

*The quadratic congruence has a repeated root if and only if $\Delta \equiv 0$.*

**Why there are precisely "two" squareroots**

Suppose that $d$ is a quadratic residue. Then there is some $s$ such that $s^2=d$. How to prove that the only solutions to $x^2\equiv d$ has the only solutions $x\equiv \pm s$?

Simply, as before: we need $x^2-d\equiv 0$. Therefore $(x-s)(x+s)\equiv 0$. But $p$ is prime, so either $p| x+s$ or $p|x-s$. Therefore $x\equiv \pm s$.

**What if we use other representatives**

All that we do is completely done at the level of residues modulo $p$. This means that adding multiples of $p$ doesn't affect anything, because it has the effect of adding zeroes. For example, if the central coefficient is $b=-(1+mp)$, then the discriminant changes accordingly
$$\Delta = d+2mp+m^2p^2$$
which by the way it is $\equiv d$ modulo $p$.

We have $\Delta\equiv 0$ modulo $p$  if and only if $d\equiv 0$ modulo $p$.

We have $\Delta$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if there is some $s$ such that $s^2\equiv \Delta$ modulo $p$. This means that $s^2\equiv d$ modulo $p$, and so it is equivalent to asking that $d$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Moreover any choice of $\sqrt \Delta$ is valid as a choice of $\sqrt d$.

The solutions modulo $p$ are still given by the formula

$$x \equiv \frac{1+mp \pm \sqrt \Delta}{2}$$ because in fact it gives the same results, modulo $p$, as the formula
$$x \equiv \frac{1 \pm \sqrt d}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Over any field, the roots of higher multiplicity of a polynomial $f(X)$ are the common roots of that polynomial and its (formal) derivative $f'(X)$. This follows because the product rule tells us that the derivative of $(X-a)^2g(X)$ is $2(X-a)g(x)+(X-a)^2g'(X)$, i.e., $a$ is a root of both. (This method works even if the common root is not yet in the field we consider but in a field extension instead)

In the case of $f(X)=X^2-X-c$, we wan a root $f$ has in common with $f'(X)=2X-1$. As long as $p$ is odd, this common root in the field $\Bbb F_p$ can only be the only root o $f'$, namely $\frac12$ -- and that is a root of $f$ iff $f(\frac12)=0$, i.e., iff $\frac14-\frac12-c=0$, or: $c=\frac14$.